# Generate thumbnail image from PDF file that is located in SharePoint Server?

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, javascript

I have a PDF file on the sharepoint server, I wanted to access that PDF file and generate a thumbnail image on the fly. Is any of the Javascript frameworks supports this feature to implement..

Can anyone help me out to convert the PDF file into an thumbnail image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of products can view PDF files online and generate a thumbnail image, but I recommended this tool document viewer that can preview some types of files by thumbnail, also view this PDF file online.http://www.boostsolutions.com/sharepoint-document-viewer.html